# Why are printed memory addresses in Rust a mix of both 40-bit and 48-bit addresses?

Tags: memory, rust

I'm trying to understand the way Rust deals with memory and I've a little program that prints some memory addresses:

```
fn main() {
    let a = &&&5;
    let x = 1;
    println!(" {:p}", &x);
    println!(" {:p} \n {:p} \n {:p} \n {:p}", &&&a, &&a, &a, a);
}
```

This prints the following (varies for different runs):

```
0x235d0ff61c
0x235d0ff710 
0x235d0ff728 
0x235d0ff610 
0x7ff793f4c310
```

This is actually a mix of both 40-bit and 48-bit addresses. Why this mix? Also, can somebody please tell me why the addresses (2, 3, 4) do not fall in locations separated by 8-bytes (since `std::mem::size_of_val(&a)` gives 8)? I'm running Windows 10 on an AMD x-64 processor (Phenom || X4) with 24GB RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the addresses do have the same size, Rust is just not printing trailing 0-digits.

The actual memory layout is an implementation detail of your OS, but the reason that `a` prints a location in a different memory area than all the other variables is, that `a` actually lives in your loaded binary, because it is a value that can already be calculated by the compiler. All the other variables are calculated at runtime and live on the stack.

See the compilation result on https://godbolt.org/z/kzSrDr:

`.L__unnamed_4` contains the value 5; `.L__unnamed_5`, `.L__unnamed_6` and `.L__unnamed_1` are `&5` `&&5` and `&&&5`.

So `.L__unnamed_1` is what on your system is at `0x7ff793f4c310`. While `0x235d0ff???` is on your stack and calculated in the red and blue areas of the code.

Answer (score 3):

> This is actually a mix of both 40-bit and 48-bit addresses. Why this mix?

It's not really a mix, Rust just doesn't display leading zeroes. It's really about where the OS maps the various components of the program (data, bss, heap and stack) in the address space.

> Also, can somebody please tell me why the addresses (2, 3, 4) do not fall in locations separated by 8-bytes (since std::mem::size_of_val(&a) gives 8)?

Because `println!` is a macro which expands to a bunch of stuff in the stackframe, so your values are not defined next to one another in the frame final code (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5b812bf11e51461285f51f95dd79236b). Though even if they were there'd be no guarantee the compiler wouldn't e.g. be reusing now-dead memory to save up on frame size.